# Reset password in laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I'm trying to combine Laravel project and Nova admin panel. In the project I need to reset Nova password, But there is a FatalThrowableError error in PasswordBroker.php file.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSbNS.png)

This is my PasswordBroker.php file.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use UnexpectedValueException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker as PasswordBrokerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class PasswordBroker implements PasswordBrokerContract
{
    protected $tokens;
    protected $users;
    protected $passwordValidator;

    public function __construct(TokenRepositoryInterface $tokens,
                                UserProvider $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->tokens = $tokens;
    }


    public function sendResetLink(array $credentials)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        $user->sendPasswordResetNotification(
            $this->tokens->create($user)
        );

        return static::RESET_LINK_SENT;
    }

    public function reset(array $credentials, Closure $callback)
    {

        $user = $this->validateReset($credentials);

        if (! $user instanceof CanResetPasswordContract) {
            return $user;
        }

        $password = $credentials['password'];

        $callback($user, $password);

        $this->tokens->delete($user);

        return static::PASSWORD_RESET;
    }


    protected function validateReset(array $credentials)
    {
        if (is_null($user = $this->getUser($credentials))) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        if (! $this->validateNewPassword($credentials)) {
            return static::INVALID_PASSWORD;
        }

        if (! $this->tokens->exists($user, $credentials['token'])) {
            return static::INVALID_TOKEN;
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function validator(Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->passwordValidator = $callback;
    }


    public function validateNewPassword(array $credentials)
    {
        if (isset($this->passwordValidator)) {
            list($password, $confirm) = [
                $credentials['password'],
                $credentials['password_confirmation'],
            ];

            return call_user_func(
                $this->passwordValidator, $credentials
            ) && $password === $confirm;
        }

        return $this->validatePasswordWithDefaults($credentials);
    }


    protected function validatePasswordWithDefaults(array $credentials)
    {
        list($password, $confirm) = [
            $credentials['password'],
            $credentials['password_confirmation'],
        ];

        return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= 6;
    }

    public function getUser(array $credentials)
    {
        $credentials = Arr::except($credentials, ['token']);

        $user = $this->users->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        if ($user && ! $user instanceof CanResetPasswordContract) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('User must implement CanResetPassword interface.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function createToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        return $this->tokens->create($user);
    }

    public function deleteToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        $this->tokens->delete($user);
    }

    public function tokenExists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
    {
        return $this->tokens->exists($user, $token);
    }

    public function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->tokens;
    }
}
```

Here I want to reset current password using email. Does anyone have a idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get any success ?